# How To Use Int Array To Color.fromargb And Create A New Image c#

Tags: c#, image, graphics, bitmap

I have this code:

```
Image IG = new Bitmap(width,height);
Graphics myGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(IG);
Color c = Color.FromArgb(BData[i]);// int[] BData
```

I want to draw a new image and save it with that color - how can I do that?

Comment: So you want the background colour of the image to be BData[i]?  What is/the value of BData[i] ?

Comment: @AlexK. Number for example BData[0] = 256 , BData[1] = 11

Comment: @AlexK. i use that color as :  bmp.SetPixel(j, i, c);

Comment: Well if they are A,R,G,B ints just use `Color.FromArgb(BData[0], BData[1], BData[2], BData[3]);`

Comment: `myGraphic.Clear(c);  IG.Save(...)`

Comment: @AlexK. That part not a problem my problem is how to use that color to make a new image as IG (look up to my Code )

Comment: @TaW that code erase the color but i want to paint thee image

Comment: It doesn't erase the color but fill the image with that color. _'Paint'_? How?? Explain! Show an example! There are __many__ methods in the Graphics object to choose from.. Or do you mean paint freehand  like MsPaint??

Comment: @TaW i want to make image like [link](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-50HBhOmpBy8/UDniD6CrU2I/AAAAAAAAACo/EAshMOLhDV8/s1600/Pixels.png)

Comment: If these are huge pixels you can use SetPixel in the MouseClick event. If they are rectangles you would use myGraphic.FillRectangle(..). - You seem to be either unable or unwilling to go into details. If you don't change this poor attitude you will be able to ever code anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[] BData = new int[4] { 255, 11, 255, 0 };
    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;
    using (System.Drawing.Image IG = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height))
    {
        using (System.Drawing.Graphics myGraphic = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(IG))
        {
            System.Drawing.Color c = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb((byte)BData[0], (byte)BData[1], (byte)BData[2], (byte)BData[3]); // int[] BData
            myGraphic.Clear(c);
        }
        IG.Save("test.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    }
```

Using 256 for the alpha is going to insert a '0' alpha, the range is 0-255.
This code saves a green .png image where the executable is.
The Save() requires an extension and/or ImageFormat. You probably have to use i+0, i+1, i+2, i+3 in the Color.FromArgb.
(byte)BData[i].

```
System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb((byte)BData[i+0], (byte)BData[i+1], (byte)BData[i+2], (byte)BData[i+3]);
```

Once the BData is filled, then just use:

```
using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(BData))
{
    System.Drawing.Image.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
    image.Save(@"test.png");
}
```

Comment: i want to make image like that [link](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-50HBhOmpBy8/UDniD6CrU2I/AAAAAAAAACo/EAshMOLhDV8/s1600/Pixels.png)